# GAMEMAKER : Assign variable value as variable key

Tags: game-maker

I tried something without success, so I ask myself if it's possible to perform this with Gamemaker.

```
array[0] = "example";
global.array[0] = 3;
```

Explicitly I want

```
array[0] = "example";
global.example = 3;
```

So;

- Is it possible to convert a value as a variable name ?
- Is it possible to convert this variable as a global ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do something like that. If you write:

```
array[0] = "example";
global.example = 3;
```

you are declaring `array[0]` for the current instance equal to the string `"example"` (without quotes), and the variable `example` of the special object `global` equal to `3`.

I guess you are trying to use the `"example"` string as a key, so I suggest you to take a look to [DS Maps](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/data%20structures/ds%20maps/). Maps are data structures in which you can look for a "key", which lets you to edit the related value. Think of a dictionary: you look for a word, and find out its meaning; well, a DS Map lets you to store "keys" (numbers, strings, any value you would assign to a simple variable) within it, and associate a value to such key. You can access the value bonded to a particular key by using the [`ds_map_find_value()`](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/data%20structures/ds%20maps/ds_map_find_value.html) function.

Comment: BTW, it's possible in GMS2 using [these](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/3_gml_overview/variable_functions/index.html) functions.

Comment: They are used primarily for compatibility when importing instances from previous versions of GM. You can use them elsewhere, but that doesn't mean you are encouraged to. That's nor good programming neither coding. By the way, these would be just a workaround to the problem asked, what @guish wants to do is not possible in GM even by using these GM2 functions.

Comment: I've done it first with ds_map, but I just asked myself if it was possible to do it without. At least, I have my answer, thanks :)